# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after moving CakePHP project from a dedicated server to another dedicated server

Tags: cakephp, redirect, server

I'm new to CakePHP and my employer asked me to move our CakePHP app from a dedicated server to another server (for testing purposes). I've copied all the files, changed app's database.php config but I'm getting a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when accessing the app on the new server.
I did not work on the app so I don't know much about it, but I have all the files.

**LE:** So, I've uploaded the app on a fresh install of CakePHP. I now have 3 .htaccess files, CakePHP says it's working, but when I try to upload DebugKit (following the install notes & having the proper version for CakePHP 2.4.3.) I get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. 
A look in Chrome's console shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF8uk.jpg). If I delete the DebugKit altogether, the page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmE3X.png) & it also has the footer from the app.
The new structure of the app is the standard one.
Please advise!

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: Well [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XmE3X.png) indicates your app "works". Which means the thing redirecting is not the webserver it's the application code - you're effectively asking readers to guess why that is. You can debug by e.g. putting `public function redirect($url) { debug($url); debug(stackTrace()); die; }` in your application controller to determine why that is. I doubt any reader can help you - Good luck.

Comment: Hey @AD7six, thanks for the quick response. The problem is that the app is working fine on the other server. On the new server, without any changes to the code, it doesn't work. After adding DebugKit I get a net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and the page isn't functioning at all. Also, I can see that the favicon is changed after adding DebugKit meaning that it now shows another app's favicon (we have more apps on the same server).

Comment: Nothing you're saying changes my prior advice. You are wasting readers time by not performing basic debug steps.

Comment: "/html/public_html/app/Controller/AppController.php (line 54)
'/'
Fatal error: Call to undefined function stackTrace() in /var/www/html/public_html/app/Controller/AppController.php on line 54" - that's the error I get after puting `public function redirect($url) { debug($url); debug(stackTrace()); die; }`

Comment: It's hard to help you when the most you're willing to do is copy and paste code, and copy and paste the output without reading it or thinking about it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess is the (apache?) `DocumentRoot` setting may be clashing with your APP config on the new server and/or the PHP settings. Have you checked your `php.ini` on the new server? What's the output of `phpinfo()` ? Once fixed HIGHLY RECOMMEND check other environment variables by <strike>turning on the DEBUG flag in `config/app.php`</strike> [For your version try `pr(Debugger::trace());`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html)  or **even better** for dev. install the [Debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit). Anyway, `DocumentRoot` should be set to `webroot` (assuming default install and directory structure).

Comment: Please check the edit. DebugKit gives me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after installing ...

Comment: After `pr(Debugger::trace());` this is the result:    *AppController::redirect() - APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 55
AppController::beforeFilter() - APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 105
call_user_func - [internal], line ??
CakeEventManager::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php, line 247
Controller::startupProcess() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 674
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 182
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 160
[main] - ROOT/html/public_html/index.php, line 109*

Comment: `AppController::redirect() - APP/Controller/AppController.php, line 55 AppController::beforeFilter()` @Laur-MarianMertea your application calls redirect in that function. As I mentioned - you need to perform some basic debugging (which includes _actually reading the output_).

Comment: @AD7six you were right. After debugging I found out that the culprit was an if clause that was redirecting the page over and over again. Thank you for the answer.